# How to make a scatter plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I don’t like the base R method. I think that many of the visualization tools from base R are awkward to use and hard to remember. I also think that the resulting visualizations are a little ugly.

Having said that, you’ll still see visualizations made with base R, so I want to show you how it’s done and what I expect to get in pics bellow

Any advice on how improve it will be appreciated

```
set.seed(55)
df <- tibble(x_var = runif(100, min = 0, max = 25)
             ,y_var = log2(x_var) + rnorm(100)
             )
plot(x = df$x_var, y = df$y_var)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can search for some `ggplot2` document and you'll plot it easily by yourself.

Comment: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/ https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/

Comment: I don't understand where the plot here came from. How to make a plot less ugly is subjective and dependent upon context, so right now this is too broad / opinion-based for SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as Darren said that is a [ggplot](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf). Another [ref](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggplot.html)

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(55)
df <- tibble(x_var = runif(100, min = 0, max = 25)
             ,y_var = log2(x_var) + rnorm(100)
)
plot(x = df$x_var, y = df$y_var)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x_var, y = y_var))+
  geom_point(color = "red")+
  geom_smooth(color = "blue")
```

Comment: It's better to indicate what packages you use.

Comment: whoops - you are right (updated).

Answer (score 2):

For simple plots, base R isn't that much different to ggplot, and with just as much (or little) typing:

```
scatter.smooth(df$x_var, df$y_var, pch=20, col="red")
grid()
```

Comment: And you could get closer to the proposed graph by adding `lpars = list(col="blue", lwd=2)` as an argument to `scatter.smooth`